# Find the double integral of $\sin (x^2+y^2)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

$\int \int_{Q}\sin(x^2+y^2)dA$ where Q is the planar region lying inside the unit circle above the graph of $y = |x|$.

I solved for x to find the x coordinate where $y=|x|$ intersects the unit circle and i got $\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$,$-\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$. However, I got stuck when trying to solve the integral. Is it polar coordinates?

Comment: Do you know Green's theorem in the plane?

Comment: The fact that the region $Q$ of integration is a sector of disk with vertex at the origin suggests using polar coordinates, as in those coordinates the integral bounds will all be constants.

Comment: I am unaware of that theorem

Answer (score 2):

Convert to polar coordiantes. The region of integration is the sector of the unit circle between $\theta=\pi/4$ and $\theta=3\pi/4$, and $0\leq r\leq 1$. Therefore, the integral is:

$$\int_{\pi/4}^{3\pi/4} \int_0^1 r\sin(r^2)\,dr\,d\theta.$$

Now this integral can be solved easily with the substitution $r^2=u$.

Comment: Or just note that it is $\int \int -\frac{1}{2} \dfrac{d}{dr} \cos(r^2) dr d\theta$ directly without bothering with the substitution.